# How to removing Lines on pageInit client script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a custom record that display a sublist like that
[sublist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iiMC.png)

I want to display lines only if they have more then 0 QTY REMAINING

for example lot SN01 need to be remove.

I want to do it on pageInit. when the user open the record he will not see the lines with 0 quantity remaining

And I get error
SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION CurrentRecord.selectLine

my code

```
function pageInit(scriptContext) {
            
            var rec = scriptContext.currentRecord;
            var count = rec.getLineCount('recmachcustrecord_slp_package_no');

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                rec.selectLine({
                    sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord_slp_package_no',
                    line: i
                });


                var qtyR = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord_slp_package_no',
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_slp_qty_remaining',
                });

                if (qtyR == 0) {
                    rec.removeLine({
                        sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord_slp_package_no',
                        line: i,
                        ignoreRecalc: true
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When removing lines from a sublist with SuiteScript, it's best to work your way up from the bottom of the list.

Removing the first line item, for example, changes the index value for all of the other line items.  Then, trying to remove the line with the index `count` gives you `SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION` because a line with that index no longer exists.

To start from the bottom:

```js
for (var i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Add your logic here.
}
```